# Any work around for this issue -- when going back and forth between pages in Firefox the focus is lost at different points

Tags: accessibility, xulrunner, jaws-screen-reader

I have a page that is rendered through xulrunner service.  There is a form and a button under the form.

For accessibility requirement, I forced the focus on the text field within the form when the user navigates to this page.  However, sometimes JAWS always reads the Post Comment button label.  Sometimes, JAWS reads the aria-label “Enter Comments”.

Here is the code:

```
<body onLoad="document.addcommentform.comment.focus()">
<input type="textarea" aria-label="Enter Comments" title="{$enterComment}" name="comment" />
<input class="Button" type="submit" value="{$postComment}" />
```

I also tried to put a visible label on the UI like this. I did more testing and found out the behavior is pretty the same.

```
<label for="addcommentform">Please enter comment 
<form method="get" action="{$self}" name="addcommentform">
<textarea title="{$enterComment}" name="comment" class="commentarea" </textarea>
<input class="Button" type="submit" value="{$postComment}" />
</form>
</label>
```

I think it is related to this known bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133771

But does anybody known any workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Jaws user and don't know of a way around this. Since Jaws tends to create it's own model of pages in a virtual buffer things can behave slightly differently then you would expect. To confirm or disprove weather it's a Jaws specific bug I would suggest trying out [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) an open source and quite good Windows screen reader.